# singular/plural mix up and vocab word confusion

Tags: grammatical-number, vocabulary

Two questions on these two sentences:

Throughout my PhD I intend to give talks to local underserved middle/high school science classes in the hopes that I can encourage students to consider **an education/career** in the sciences. Outreach to this demographic is crucial because it can lead the students to have **positively formative** future experiences in optional lab science/AP courses in high school and introductory college courses that they may not have pursued otherwise.

Should I replace **an education/career** with educations/careers?

Should I replace **positively formative** with... auspicious?